# How can I clear data from my previous <tr> in table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I design table with for when I fill the input then I push button It will show a table for next step which I want to repeat previous step data of previous step again repeat then the new data has been shown; I want to clear previous data.`

Comment: provide some examples or if possible, your code for better understanding.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example